# Automatically adjusted ImageSize across a column

Tags: front-end, options, grid-layouts

`Button` has this nice property that all `Buttons` in e.g. a `Column` will span to the size of the largest one:

```
Column @ Table[Button[i!], {i, 1, 16, 5}]
```

[image]

That is not the case in general:

```
Column @ Table[Framed[i!], {i, 1, 16, 5}]
```

[image]

Button has `ImageSize -> Full` but if we set it for `Framed` it get full width of the parent cell.

Is there a nice way to obtain `Button's` behavior in case of `Framed/Pane` and other GUI elements?

Possible workaround may be 'wrapper dependent', I'm especially interested in fixing this:

```
Column @ Table[PaneSelector[{True -> Button[i!]}, True], {i, 1, 16, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: if  cheating is allowed: `Column@Table[Button[i!, {}, Appearance -> "Framed"], {i, 1, 16, 5}]`?

Comment: @kglr yes it is but this is too specific :) I will add the real use case.

Answer (score 2):

I just dug up some option called `BoxExpandable` which does this job. I found it by inspecting the set of `FrameBoxOptions`:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {StyleDefinitions, "Input", 
   FrameBoxOptions}] /.

 s_Symbol?(StringStartsQ[SymbolName[#], "FrameBoxOptions"] &) :> 
  StringTrim[SymbolName[s], "FrameBoxOptions"]

{"BaseStyle" -> {}, "DefaultBaseStyle" -> "Framed", 
 "Enabled" -> Automatic, 
 "Appearance" -> {Automatic, "Framed", "Normal", Automatic}, 
 "Background" -> Automatic, "ImageSize" -> Automatic, 
 "ImageMargins" -> 0., "FrameMargins" -> Automatic, 
 "ContentPadding" -> True, "BaselinePosition" -> Automatic, 
 "Alignment" -> {Automatic, Automatic}, "BoxFrame" -> 1., 
 "FrameStyle" -> {}, "DefaultFrameStyle" -> {}, 
 "BoxExpandable" -> False, "StripOnInput" -> True, 
 "RoundingRadius" -> {0., 0.}, 
 "BoxMargins" -> {{0.4, 0.4}, {0.5, 0.5}}}
```

Unfortunately this only handles in initial case as it is missing from this:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {StyleDefinitions, "Input", 
   PaneSelectorBoxOptions}] /.

 s_Symbol?(StringStartsQ[SymbolName[#], 
      "PaneSelectorBoxOptions"] &) :> 
  StringTrim[SymbolName[s], "PaneSelectorBoxOptions"]

{"BaseStyle" -> {}, "DefaultBaseStyle" -> "PaneSelector", 
 "Enabled" -> Automatic, 
 "Appearance" -> {Automatic, "Palette", "Normal", Automatic}, 
 "Background" -> Automatic, "ImageSize" -> All, 
 "ImageMargins" -> Automatic, "FrameMargins" -> Automatic, 
 "ContentPadding" -> True, "BaselinePosition" -> Automatic, 
 "Alignment" -> {Automatic, Automatic}, "AutoAction" -> False, 
 "ContinuousAction" -> True, "TransitionDirection" -> Horizontal, 
 "TransitionDuration" -> 0.5, "TransitionEffect" -> Automatic}
```